# Preserve state across sibling functions -- redux, context,?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react project that is using react-router-dom with several sub pages that each have forms and are meant to be filled out in a certain successive order.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="first" element={<First />} />
          <Route path="second" element={<Second />} />
          <Route path="third" element={<Third />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want my user to see the forms in `Second` and `Third` but not submit the forms on those pages without submitting the form in `First` first. How do I preserve this information best?

I tried out Redux using [this page](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-hooks-y1w9s?file=/src/index.js) as a guide but I was surprised to see that if I click to first, submit the form, save HTTP response to the store, then click away it saves the `200` once and then gets overwritten to the default. The explanation why makes somewhat sense, but at this point react-persist seems too onerous for my needs.

Would it be possible to use Context here? Can I do the obvious and intuitive thing, where I setup a "results" context in `Layout`, set `results.first` in `First` and then use it in `Second` and `Third` without it being overwritten?

tl;dr: Is there a simple solution where I can set a value once in a child function and then read it back as many times as I want in the sibling functions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need some sort of state management for step form.
This style is called wizard step form.
You may use an existing library like [react-step-wizard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-step-wizard)
or take inspiration from the design pattern to construct your own.